# Populate Web Form From VB Application

Tags: vb.net

I have created a simple FORM in VB.NET that takes some details and then needs to log in to 3 locations using this information.

At the moment I have the code so it takes this data from the textBoxs and assigns them to 4 different variables. From there I have also opened up the three different websites.

I am having difficulties finding how I will take the variables and then populate the corresponding field on the web application. Any suggestions?

My Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Define Store variable
        Dim Store As String
        Store = Me.TextBox1.Text
        'Define IP Address variable
        Dim IPAddress As String
        IPAddress = Me.TextBox2.Text
        'Define Username variable
        Dim Username As String
        Username = Me.TextBox3.Text
        'Define Password variable
        Dim Password As String
        Password = Me.TextBox4.Text

        ' Open Store Specific URL 1
        Dim WebAddress1 As String = "http://" & IPAddress & ":"
        Process.Start(WebAddress1)
        getElementByName

        ' Open Store Specific URL 2
        Dim WebAddress2 As String = "http://somedomain2.com"
        Process.Start(WebAddress2)

        ' Open Store Specific URL 3
        Dim WebAddress3 As String = "http://somedomain3.com"
        Process.Start(WebAddress3)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is identify the element name that you want to populate.  This can typically done by going to the web page, and pressing View Source (changes by web browser, some you can right click and it will be there, some you can access through the settings button.)

Once looking at the source, you will want to find the object (usually a text box or something along those lines) where you want to send the information.  Usually these boxes have titles, like Username, or Password.  So I would recommend doing a Ctrl + F search based on the information you can see on the site.  I see in your code you have GetElementByName, and that's exactly what you'll do. You will want to store

Here's an example code:

```
Dim IE As Object 'Internet explorer object
Dim objCollection As Object 'Variable used for cycling through different elements

'Create IE Object
IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate("https://somewebsite.com/") 'Your website

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.DoEvents() 'This allows the site to load first
Loop

'Find the field you are looking for and store it into the objCollection variable
objCollection = IE.document.getelementsbyname("CustomerInfo.AccountNumber") 'The "CustomerInfo.AccountNumber" is the name of the element I looked for in this case.

'Call element, and set value equal to the data you have from your form
objCollection(0).Value = MainForm.tbLoan.Text

' Clean up
IE = Nothing
objCollection = Nothing
```

This should be a good start for you.  There are multiple resources on this site that might be able to give you additional information when it comes to entering data into websites using vb.net.

Hopefully this helps!